# sudden segmentation fault with value optimized out

Tags: c++, eclipse, segmentation-fault, debian

I have 2 environments of work:

- Laptop with Debian on VirtualBox
- PC with normally instaled same    version of Debian

I am using two systems because some H/W do not work with VB.
Project includes usage of pthreads and ncurses.

Suddenly I have an seg-fault error on the PC, when at the same time everything works fine on Laptop+VB. Error is in line not connected to either pthreads or ncurses
I am using Eclipse to develop my software, procedure of migrating projects was:

1. copy files form Laptop on USB-drive
2. Import project to Eclipse workspace on PC

Up to now everything was OK. Settings of tool-chain seems to be equal on both.

CODE:

```
Config::~Config() {
    std::map<std::string, Setting*>::iterator configIterator;
        for(configIterator = config.begin(); configIterator != config.end(); ++configIterator){
            delete configIterator->second;
        }
    config.clear();
}
```

seg-fault appears on *delete* operator. When checking of object existence before *del*, it looks like all of them are in memory.

this is the way of adding config entries:

```
config.insert(std::pair<std::string,Setting*>("language", new Setting("en_en")));
```

My question is double:

1. Why I have optimized values even with -O0 ?
2. What should I look for to find why this happening ?

I know this is something allocating or deallocating memory, but I do not even know from where to begin. I tried to remove part of code with errors, but this gave me more errors in unknown places.

[EDIT]
@comments below:

I found that actual error is in to-string casting operator overloaded method, but:

```
Setting::operator std::string(){
    std::stringstream sstr;
    switch(what){
        case STRING: sstr << str; break;
        case INT: sstr << i; break;
        case FLOAT: sstr << f; break;
        default: sstr << str; break;
    }
    sstr << std::flush;
    return sstr.str();
}
```

when I change this for ONLY returning some dummy string like  >> return "x" << there is no seg-fault. 
So.. what is wrong with the code above ? And why this works on VB but not on PC.

Comment: Could it be that the VM is running with one core only, and the PC with more than 1? This would make race conditions more likely on the PC than on the VM.

Comment: There can be a lot of causes. One common cause would be if one of the pointers had already been deleted or the same pointer was in the map twice. Another would be if another thread is using one of the objects you are deleting. You really shouldn't use a map of dumb pointers. You should either use a collection specifically designed for pointers or use smart pointers.

Comment: You mention pthread, does Config can be use from many thread? While the Setting instances are deleted, their pointers are left in the config map. Any other thread using Config may use a deleted pointer.

Comment: Laptop suports virtualization (core i7) and in VB there are 2 cores assigned, PC has also 2 cores. I am using clean pthreads so I need to handle "smartness" by myself. Config is part of a Singleton class of ConfigManager. Only from ConfigManager settings can be read. In addition they are never removed until "end of program"

Comment: I'd probably use a smart pointer like `shared_ptr<Setting>` instead of a raw `Setting*` there, but that may not help resolve your problem.

Comment: In fact, I just removed all thread-startups, leaving only Config strictly in main(). This changed nothing ;/

Comment: What is in Setting's destructor then?

Comment: Setting is an Union, so different types of data can be stored as Setting. In destructor there is "deallocation of char*", when Setting stores chain of signs.

Comment: First of all make some valgrind test and see is it all right there with memory

Comment: Definitely +1 to Mart.ini's comment. valgrind will catch it straight away, whereas gdb won't detect the error until well after it happened, which is much less helpful.

Comment: @Mart.ini thanks.. that actually helped. It appears I had memory leak in completely different place, but influence was major.

Comment: From the type I see in the operator, I guest str is a char* and is not always set or it lose its value, maybe it was set with a string::c_str() or a char[] local to a function. And does Config is filled with the same values in VB and PC?